# Dúvida sobre o eclipse [Workspaces Master]

Tags: java, classes, eclipse

Olá, gostaria de saber o por que meu eclipse trata um projeto como [Workspaces Master]
E o por que das classes ficarem com um ponto de interrogação.
(Este projeto foi importado).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A interrogação não seria do controle de versão (imagino que o arquivo não foi adicionado) ?

Comment: Poderia ser, porém não estou utilizando controle de versão

Answer (score 0):

Este símbolo indica que esses arquivos não foram adicionados a uma ferramenta de versionamento.

Se o projeto não está utilizando controle de versionamento, a pasta onde o projeto foi importado possivelmente está.

Pode dar uma checada na [lista de símbolos do controle de versionamento do eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-cvs-decorations.htm).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!